# -XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak couldn't create jvm?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, jvm-arguments, heap-dump

When I add to the jvm parameters following one

> -XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak

I'm getting an error that JVM couldn't be started.

> Could not create Java virtual machine

Java version I'm using is `1.6.0_21`.

What I'm doing wrong? Do I need to set up any others parameters?

Comment: This usually means that the heap size was too small, or there wasn't enough resources. It could also be a bug.  I would try update 45 which has many bug fixed compared with update 21

Comment: According to this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionxx.htm the -XX options apply only to the Oracle JRockit JVM ... and indeed on my JVM it says unrecognized option ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think it is not supported by JDK 1.6 , did you try with JDK 1.5.

For more you can refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577342/unrecognized-vm-option-heapdumponctrlbreak).

You can achieve the same thing by using [jmap](http://www.startux.de/java) introduced in JDK 1.6

Thanks

Comment: +1 It doesn't appear on this list of options http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: Is there any alternative for this parameter? Unfortunatelly I don't have the possiblity to downgrade java even for test it. But I would like to make a dump in each moment of running application.

Comment: i have never used jmap , but it sounds promising , you can have a try with that. Thanks

Comment: I found that Java VisualVM which is delivered together with JDK is also a very useful and userfriendly tool.

Comment: ... or you can make a dump directly from Eclipse Memory Analyzer which I'm gonna to use.